# Spring boot application is built but Annotation cannot be found?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I opened a project ,since got another project going, decided to change .m2 directory ,so changed it to /users/*********/my-m2/my-settings.xml, and /users/*********/my-m2/my-repository in Build,Execution Deployment---Maven section ,after that did mvn clean install so build is done but @SpringBootApplication is not found.
This is my pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo111111</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo111111</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

also downloaded another maven and configured MAVEN_HOME.

Comment: `decided to change .m2 directory ,so changed it to /users//my-m2/my-settings.xml, and /users//my-m2/my-repository in Build,Execution Deployment---Maven section` Why?

Comment: Why? The `.m2` is the central location for Maven on your system, you don't need to have a new one per project.